# core dump when calling vsnprintf

Tags: c++, printf

i am on ubuntu 12.04, with uname -a:
Linux lu057801 3.2.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:16:45 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

g++ --version:
Linux lu057801 3.2.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:16:45 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I get a core dump in a call to vsnprintf. The following is the entire code that produces the issue:

```
// compile: g++ -g -o test vsnprintf_test.c

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

void vout(char *string, char *fmt, ...);
char fmt1 [] = "%s  %s  %s\n";

size_t snprintf_1(char* buffer, const size_t bufSize, const char* format, ...);
size_t vsnprintf_1(char* buffer, const size_t bufSize, const char* format, va_list args);

int main(void)
{
  char * format = "%s";
  char buffer[] = "/var/tmp\0"; //char * buffer = "/var/tmp\0";
  int bufSize=sizeof(buffer); //int bufSize=11;
  snprintf_1(buffer, bufSize, format);
}


size_t snprintf_1(char* buffer, const size_t bufSize, const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    size_t rc = vsnprintf_1(buffer, bufSize, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return rc;
}


size_t vsnprintf_1(char* buffer, const size_t bufSize, const char* format, va_list args)
{
    int rc = 0;
    rc = vsnprintf(buffer, bufSize, format, args);
}
```

Compiling as: g++ -g -o test vsnprintf_test.c and running will give me the following backtrace:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/mafunk/software/MattsSnippets/test 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_vsnprintf (string=0x400738 "/var/tmp", maxlen=<optimized out>, format=0x400730 "%s", args=0x7fffffffe0b0) at vsnprintf.c:118
118     vsnprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  _IO_vsnprintf (string=0x40072f "/var/tmp", maxlen=<optimized out>, format=0x40072c "%s", args=0x7fffffffe0b0) at vsnprintf.c:118
#1  0x0000000000400639 in vsnprintf_1 (buffer=0x40072f "/var/tmp", bufSize=11, format=0x40072c "%s", args=0x7fffffffe0b0)
at vsnprintf_test.c:36
#2  0x00000000004005f2 in snprintf_1 (buffer=0x40072f "/var/tmp", bufSize=11, format=0x40072c "%s") at vsnprintf_test.c:27
#3  0x0000000000400541 in main () at vsnprintf_test.c:19
```

I guess i am not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The segfault is caused because the destination you are trying to write to is a *string literal*.

In addition, the call `snprintf_1(buffer, bufSize, format);` is passed a `"%s"` format string but no other arguments. The format string expects an additional `char *` parameter and the code will read random memory on the call stack for the string pointer you didn't provide.

Comment: That's the other error, code should be `snprintf_1(buffer, bufSize, format, "some string here");`.

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying a string literal, this is undefined behaviour. Change to this and it might work (although your buffer still looks too small to me).

```
char buffer[] = "/var/tmp\0";
```

In this code `buffer` is an array, not a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: Might also want to fix up the bufsize to match, too

Comment: Yes, `bufSize = sizeof buffer;`.

Comment: So i changed to char buffer[] = "/var/tmp\0"; int bufSize=sizeof(buffer); but i am still getting a core dump. I'll change it above, but leave the old way comment out.

Comment: @user990234, Blastfurnace has the answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

your buffer is too small

```
char * buffer = "/"/var/tmp/.SHM_SAP_IPMM_0008_no-sid\0";  **//37 char** 

int bufSize=**35**;
```

Comment: Sorry, had to change something, you are too fast for me. Let me get it straight. Ok, i believe the post is now as it was intended. Anyway, the issue still exists.

Comment: oh, ok  :). let me take a look

Comment: your buffer is still too small. \0 is counting

Comment: The real problem isn't the size of the destination but because it's a _string literal_ and any attempt to write to it will segfault.